# Magento 2 Configurable product radio button after need to short description show

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

facing some issues on magento 2 configurable product the variation have radio button i want to show short description for each variation radio button below, every product having different variation.

Sample screen -- https://ibb.co/CHnM128

my product url -- http://magento.rudrakshamart.com/bazee-damase-duma-truma.html

How to achieve this plz help me..

Thanks...

Comment: You can use custom option as radio button from admin

Comment: Open the product in edit mode.Scroll down and expand  the Customizable Options section. Then, tap Add Option.

Comment: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/settings-advanced-custom-options.html

Comment: i want to same this screen https://ibb.co/CHnM128

Comment: i enable radio button custom option but i want to enter short description text for each variation